# Weird scons v8 compilation issue

Tags: compilation, fedora, scons, v8

I use fedora 15, here is what i get when i try to run scons :

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o obj/release/accessors.o -c -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fvisibility=hidden -Wall -Werror -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wnon-virtual-dtor -pedantic -m32 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -ansi -DV8_TARGET_ARCH_IA32 -DENABLE_DEBUGGER_SUPPORT -Isrc src/accessors.cc
scons: *** [obj/release/accessors.o] Error 127
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

If i try to run the g++ command, it works w/out any warning and the .o file is generated.

What's weird is that it's working on another computer w/ fedora 15.

Any help? Thanks.

PS : scons -v :

```
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.1.0.r5357[MODIFIED], 2011/09/09 21:31:03, by bdeegan on ubuntu
    engine: v2.1.0.r5357[MODIFIED], 2011/09/09 21:31:03, by bdeegan on ubuntu
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011 The SCons Foundation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your $PATH variable in the SConscript.

Error 127 means that your builder (scons, here) has not been able to locate a required executable (g++).

If your PATH is OK, see if you can set manually the g++ full path.

Comment: That was a path issue, i had to remove some environment variables.

Comment: I have the same issues. I put the path by hand to the g++ excutable and I still can't compile. It still returns with error 127. I can run the command by hand. I'm using an Asus Transformer Prime tablet with the Ubuntu userspace in it.